# How to monitor K8S pods in percent properly ? I am getting values well over 100%. Please any solution?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, cpu-usage, promql

Issue can be for example in jobs like GitLab runner where it creates pod for every CICD pipeline but containers have the same name in the pods.
This is what i am using currently
`sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{container!=""}[10m])) by (pod) * 100`

Comment: i got hint to use ```kube_pod_container_resource_requests/limits``` with {resource="cpu"} to gain better overview which i am trying now. But i dont know how to filter same containers with same name. Fyi